# Enter is to entrant as exit is to *

Tags: single-word-requests, analogy

A person who enters something is called an entrant.

What is a person who exits something called?

Comment: No special word. You can make one up and force everybody to use it.

Comment: @JohnLawler haha.  not sure if you are being serious.  But if you are, i choose "exiter"

Comment: Good one. Maybe you can work it into the limerick about the lady who was so pretty that men craned their necks at her.

Comment: Perhaps 'exiteer' will pattern after 'Brexiteer'. But it could come to mean 'one in favour of exiting'. // 'Exit' being an antonym of 'enter', 'leavers' is semantically fine (though may not be appropriate in some contexts).

Comment: Quitter? Leaver? It depends what they're exiting: someone leaving a job, contract, or political party is different to someone leaving a building or an airplane in mid-flight.

Comment: Actually, 'exiter' is listed by Wiktionary. Research is important on ELU.

Comment: A person who enters a competition may be an entrant but not someone who enters a building....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the context, you would specify the person exiting something by the nature of their exit:

For example in a competition:

- "*drop-out*"
- "*loser/defeated*"
- "*victor*"

If talking about an institution:

- "*alumnus*"

Depending on what you consider a "proper" word, you can also say "*exiter*" which has [at least one precedent](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/exiter):

> "High lateral entry is associated with low gross entry and exit rates and patent shares, low relative size (in terms of patents) of **exiters** (in particular, lateral **exiters**), and net entrants and **exiters**."
>
> 1999, Alfonso Gambardella, Franco Malerba, The Organization of Economic Innovation in Europe (page 53)

Answer (score 0):

**leaver**

This is marked "UK":

> school-leaver
> noun [ C ] UK
> *a young person who is about to leave or has just left secondary school*
> [Cambredge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/school-leaver?q=leaver)